# mongoDB geoNear command with count

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, geospatial

I am using the geoNear commang with mongoid in order to retrive a document collection ordered by distance. I need the distance for each document in the collection which is why I am having to resort to the geoNear command.
Given the following command:

```
category_ids = ["list", "of", "ids"]
cmd = Hash.new
cmd[:geoNear] = :poi
cmd[:near] = [params[:location][:x], params[:location][:y]]
cmd[:query] = {
  "$or" => [
    {primary_category_id: {"$in" => category_ids}},
    {category_ids: {"$in" => category_ids}}
  ]
}
cmd[:spherical] = true
cmd[:num] = num
res = Poi.collection.database.command cmd
```

My problem is that I require the total number of results in the collection. Sure I could just run another query that just counts the number of items that satisfy the query part of the command, however that would be pretty inefficient and also not very extendible as every change I make in the command would have to be reflected in the count query. Just adding a maxDistance would land me in a whole heap of trouble.

Another option would be to go with find and calculate the distance manually but again I would like to avoid that.

So my question is there a clever way of getting the number of documents returned by the command (minus the `num`) without having to run a separate query or having to calculate the distance manually and go with find.

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this all inline rather than inside a language? I had a similar situation where I just incremented a count while pulling results off the list.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what you mean by inline. By a counter do you mean counting the results from the results in Ruby? If you mean including a counter in the mongoDB command, do you have an example of how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use facet for the same after geoNear use facet one will project the documents and in other you can use group by _id null and use the count in group to count the total number of documents.